# Erro no projeto em Eclipse: "no resource round that Marches The given name"

Tags: android, android-layout

Criei um projeto no eclipse porem apresenta erro na MainActivity.java, na classe R, na pasta res>values>styles, já dei clear.

> Error: no resource round that Marches The given name ' Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'.

Comment: Gostaria de saber por que tanto `...` http://pt.stackoverflow.com/revisions/75516/1 ?

Comment: kkkkk foi mal. Eu não sei adicionar os erros aqui..como faço?

Comment: Isto deve lhe ajudar http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/formatting . No entanto já editei sua pergunta, seja bem vindo ao SOpt.

Comment: [youtube]https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HpXoCfoX_QY[/youtube]                consegui através deste link ai.